# Using Linq to identify the encoding declaration

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Is there a way with Linq to XML to isolate and retrieve the attributes of the encoding declaration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

It seems like you can initalize an XDoc or XElement with the whole document or just a starting element, but how would you Isolate this tag... it doesnt have a name... or at least I dont know if it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [XDocument.Declaration Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
string encoding = document.Declaration.Encoding;
```

As a bonus, you can get the version number too:

```
string version = document.Declaration.Version;
```

Comment: Oh, yes thats quite nice :). Thanks Bojin